# Triggering a Jenkins build on GitHub merge event

Tags: github, jenkins

I installed Github Plugin and set the Poll SCM to 1 minute.
Below is a picture of my configuration.

[image: build triggers]

So when I commit on my repo, a minute after that the build starts.

On my github repo I created a webhook (but it timesout) and a service which doesnt work either (I think the problem is on my jenkins server).

But the checkbox "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" is missing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On the [v1.25.1 release](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin/releases/tag/v1.25.1) of the GitHub plugin, trigger `Build when a change is pushed to GitHub` has been renamed to **GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling**.

Comment: this still does not trigger my build. Did you have to do the "Add Webhook" stuff inside of GitHub project? And if so, how did you come up with the URL?

Comment: Correct you need to add a webhook on your git project. URl format : http://<jenkinsDomain>/jenkins/gitlab/build_now/<projectName>