# How can I trigger jenkins build on merging github branches?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, merge, jenkins-plugins

We can trigger jenkins build upon github commit. But I want to trigger jenkins build after merging test branch to development on github.

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple options in the jenkins.
1 ) Build when a change is pushed to GitHub _ this triggers if code is merged into that repo
2 ) GitHub Pull Request Builder - This will be triggered if any PR is created against the repo 
BTW we are using Jenkins ver. 1.570.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934478/build-when-a-change-is-pushed-to-github-is-missing